# Absolute path to subfolder

Tags: apache

I have apache setup to serve sites in `/var/www`, and I have many sites in this directory. Now I don't own any of these sites and cannot update any of their content.

The problem is most of these websites use absolute path for their assets like `<img src="/img/foo.png">`, and apache tries to load them from `/var/www/` instead of say `/var/www/example1/`.

I tried to add a `.htaccess` to `/var/www/` to rewrite every paths to assets to a subdirectory, but I can't find a way to make assets from `/var/www/example1/` loaded from this directory and assets from `var/www/example2/` loaded from `example2` instead of `example1`.

Is there a way to make this work? I don't really like the `.htaccess` solution in `/var/www/`, at first I wanted to use a vHost configuration for every sites but I didn't find how to do it (at least without having a domain name for each site).

Thanks!

Comment: You will not be able to do this via a couple of `.htaccess` files, rather use some [vhost.conf configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) for this.

Comment: I tried that first but I couldn't make it work... I thought setting a `DocumentRoot` for every sites would work but it doesn't. And I am not sure whether it should have worked or not...